# How do I make a subdomain (e.g. mirror.site.com) on a LAMP server?

Tags: lamp, webserver

I pretty much want to make a main site that's a proper site, then a subdomain (I think that's what it's called) so I can also make a thing where you go through the folders (the "Index of /folder/folder/file" thing (don't know the proper name).

Sorry for the horrible explanation.

Comment: If you want to have something like `http://website.com` and `http://mail.website.com` then I think you need to create additional records on the DNS.

Comment: DNS and web server config needed google subdomain and A record

Comment: LAMP is okay to start but for better performance there are other web servers out there in open source.